# Perl hash negation

Tags: perl

Can you help me correct the code snippet.

I want to list the server which is type eq xyz but not with namedservers.

```
our %SERVERS = (
  "rajesh1" => {type => 'xyz', sha => 'ram'},
  "rajesh2" => {type => 'xyz', sha => 'sita'},
  "rajesh3" => {type => 'xyz', named => ["raa"]},
  "rajesh4" => {type => 'xxx', named => ["rajjaj"]},
);

while ( my $mServer = each(%SERVERS) ) 
{ 
  if ("$SERVERS{$mServer}{type}" eq "xyz" && !"$SERVERS{$mServer}{named}" ) 
  {
    print "Name of the server is $mServer\n";        
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
rajesh1
rajesh2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're missing a semicolon after the definition of `%SERVERS`.
2. You start calling it `$mServer`, then later say `$gServer`. Pick one!
3. Get rid of the quotes around `$SERVERS{$mServer}{type}` and `$SERVERS{$mServer}{named}` (once you've changed `gServer` to `mServer`—you don't need them.
4. You expect to see "rajesh1 rajesh2", but none of them have type `"prod"`. How is that possible? Assuming you change their type to `"prod"` …
5. You expect to see "rajesh1 rajesh2", but you print `"Name of the server is $mServer\n"` (once you change `gServer` to `mServer`). Changing that to just `"$mServer\n"`, and …
6. … it should work.

Hence:

```perl
our %SERVERS = (
    "rajesh1" =>  {type => 'prod', sha => 'ram'},
    "rajesh2" =>  {type => 'prod', sha => 'sita'},
    "rajesh3" =>  {type => 'xyz',  named => ["raa"]},
    "rajesh4" =>  {type => 'xxx',  named => ["rajjaj"]},
);

while (my $mServer = each %SERVERS) { 
    if ($SERVERS{$mServer}{type} eq "prod" && !$SERVERS{$mServer}{named}) {
        print "$mServer\n";
    }
}
```

Then:

```bsh
$ perl test.pl 
rajesh1
rajesh2
$
```

Comment: Sorry for typo. I just corrected. Let me go through your other inputs as well

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `defined`.

```
if ($SERVERS{$mServer}->{type} eq "xyz" &&
    ! defined $SERVERS{$mServer}->{named} )
...
```

You were using an undefined variable `$gServer` where apparently you meant to use the loop variable `$mServer`.  You should `use strict; use warnings;` in all your scripts; that makes it easy to catch this mistake (and a slew of others).

I use the indirection operator `->` to access the contents of hash references as a matter of preference.  I also removed some gratuitous quoting as a stylistic change.

Comment: You **do not need to use** `->`; it's implied between brackets (see [perlref's "Using References", item 3](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)), because there's no way you could define a *non-reference* hash or array as the value of a key. It would only be required if `$SERVERS` was a hashref, and we meant that and not `%SERVERS`. That said, your code wouldn't break as it is, so I'm not downvoting you or anything.

Comment: Len: Thanks, updated my answer. Some of the things I was griping about have been fixed by edits to the question, too.

Comment: likewise! :) I'm glad you flagged `->` as a style thing (I'm not against it per se, just don't like to see it called mandatory when not so).

Answer (score 1):

Complete sample, catching both of `each`'s return values, which reduces visual clutter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our %SERVERS = (
    "rajesh1" => {type => 'xyz',  sha => 'ram'},
    "rajesh2" => {type => 'xyz',  sha => 'sita'},
    "rajesh3" => {type => 'xyz',  named => ["raa"]},
    "rajesh4" => {type => 'xxx',  named => ["rajjaj"]},
    "rajesh5" => {type => 'prod', sha => 'ram'},
    "rajesh6" => {type => 'prod', named => ["jajaja"]},
);

while ( my( $mServer, $mData ) = each %SERVERS ) { 
    if ($mData->{type} eq "prod" && !$mData->{named}) {
        print "Name of the server is $mServer\n";
    }
}
```